# NavigationBar title with two UIBarButtons

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to set the title of the `UINavigationBar`. If i don't add the `UIBarButtons`, i can see the title, if i add them, i can't. I want to see both

```
var cancelBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Cancel".localized,
    style: .plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(cancelButtonTouched(sender:))
)
var doneBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Done",
    style: .plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(doneButtonTouched(sender:))
)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupRightNavBarButtons()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Title"
}

func setupRightNavBarButtons(){
    self.doneBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBarButtonItem
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBarButtonItem
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way for a view controller to set itself up for the navigation bar is to set its own `navigationItem`.

Change:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Title"
```

to:

```
self.title = "Title" // sets the navigationItem title
```

or:

```
navigationItem.title = "Title"
```